How to prevent the page from being disposed while preventing the main form being closed by user in MAUI?
I've a MAUI App in .NET 8. When user close the window from taskbar or with the close button, app should keep running in tray area instead of closing completely. After some research I found this solution and it works as intended. But there is one problem when trying to cancel closed event. Maui.Controls.Window and its Page properties are being disposed already. When the window is reopened from the tray area, only a blank window remains. How can I prevent the window from closing before its contents are disposed?
The code from the solution I mentioned in the reference is below. This is placed in MainWindow.xaml.cs
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
           base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
           Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
           IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
           Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
           Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
           window.Closed += (o, e) =>
            {
               e.Handled = true; 
               // this line will cancel the closed event
               (appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).Minimize();
               // this line will minimize the window
            };
#endif
      }


You just need to add the code below to prevent the window from closing before its contents are disposed. BTW, for the Blank Window as you described in your post, it is due to the AppWindow was closed by the Window.
appWindow.Closing += (o, e) =>{ e.Cancel = true; }

